# Dictionary<object,bool> as a list with checkboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, converters, itemscontrol

I'm trying to achive List with CheckBoxes, but has some problems with binding value of Dictionary to `IsChecked` property in XAML.

My list template:

XAML

```
<ItemsControl Name="lb" ItemsSource="{Binding Movies}" BorderThickness="0">
    <ItemsControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ItemsControl">
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.Style>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Key.MovieId}" IsChecked="{Binding Converter={StaticResource DictConvert}, ConverterParameter=Key}" Command="{Binding DummyCommand}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Converter

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    KeyValuePair<Movie, bool> bla = (KeyValuePair<Movie, bool>)value;
    var dict = value as Dictionary<Movie, bool>;
    List<KeyValuePair<Movie,bool>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<Movie, bool>>();
    list.Add(bla);
    dict = list.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, k => k.Value);

    if (dict != null)
    {
        return true;
    }

    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Debugger hits this "return true" line, so it should work, but I'm getting `XamlParseException`. Anyone can help me with this?, I've tried to create ObservableDictionary but gave up with that - it's the only way?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can set `ConverterParameter` to the databinding value like you're trying (also syntax is not correct). Redo your converter into a `IMultiValueConverter`, and pass in the Key and Value as separate bindings, and you should be good to go.

Also, remove the `throw new NotImplementedException()` line in your code - that will make it crash.

Comment: Could you please post sample code for that? when I'm doing multivalueconverter I have problems with convertback method.